# My magento product pictures has gone missing by themselves

Tags: php, magento

I'm having a problem with my magento system.

For some reason some of the products pictures disappeared by themselves.

I noticed it today as i was surfing my site. all i know of the issue is that today earlier the pictures were there and now they're gone.. i did check my ftp to see if the pictures are still there and they are..

anyone suffered from this problem or knows what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out your permissions? Does folder media have the right ones?